# Records spanning over multiple lines in graphviz

Tags: visualization, graphviz, dot

I am trying to visualize a rather complex structure in the dot language.
Because the record is big, I would like to write the code in mulitple lines. So instead of:

```
A11[label="A.11 Access Control|{A.11.1 Business requirements for access control|A.11.2 User access management}|{A.11.3 User responsibilities|A.11.4 Network access control}|{A.11.5 Operating System access control|A.11.6 Application & information access control}|A.11.7 Mobile computing & teleworking"];
```

I would like to enter it somewhat like this

```
A11[label="A.11 Access Control|
           {A.11.1 Business requirements for access control|A.11.2 User access management}|
           {A.11.3 User responsibilities|A.11.4 Network access control}|
           {A.11.5 Operating System access control|A.11.6 Application & information access control}|
           A.11.7 Mobile computing & teleworking"];
```

Unfortunately the parser for dot complains about a "string running past line end" or something alike. Does anyone know how to denote a linebreak in the code? I tried a `\` at the end of the line, but it didn't seem to work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
graph G{
A11[label="A.11 Access Control|\n\
{A.11.1 Business requirements for access control|A.11.2 User access management}|\n\
{A.11.3 User responsibilities|A.11.4 Network access control}|\n\
{A.11.5 Operating System access control|A.11.6 Application & information access control}|\n\
A.11.7 Mobile computing & teleworking"];
}
```

You can also do like

```
label = "line1\n" +
        "line2\n" + ...
```

Comment: Hi livibetter. No that is not what I meant. I would like to use multiple lines in the source code only. Just to make editing easier. So your solution without the \n but with just the \ does the trick

Comment: I guess I assumed your want to the result to have multi-line too quick because I saw a really long line in result. Anyway, I am glad that I still can help with multi-line.

Comment: Any ideas why this does not work in http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/? I tried copy-pasting the above, inserting `A11[ shape = Mrecord, label= ...` and I only get a node with "A11" and no other text inside?! Also, if I change `label="A.11 Access Control|\n\` to `label="A.11 Access Control|"+` and add a double quote on the next line, I get "ERROR: expected ... but "+" found"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape newlines without terminating the string. Note that you can insert whitespace before each `{}` to indent the lines in the source code. This whitespace has no effect on the generated graph.

```
graph G{
    node [shape=record];
    A11[label="A.11 Access Control|\
        {A.11.1 Business requirements for access control|A.11.2 User access management}|\
        {A.11.3 User responsibilities|A.11.4 Network access control}|\
        {A.11.5 Operating System access control|A.11.6 Application & information access control}|\
        A.11.7 Mobile computing & teleworking"
    ];
}
```

Demo [here](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=graph%20G%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drecord%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20A11%5Blabel%3D%22A.11%20Access%20Control%7C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BA.11.1%20Business%20requirements%20for%20access%20control%7CA.11.2%20User%20access%20management%7D%7C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BA.11.3%20User%20responsibilities%7CA.11.4%20Network%20access%20control%7D%7C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BA.11.5%20Operating%20System%20access%20control%7CA.11.6%20Application%20%26%20information%20access%20control%7D%7C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A.11.7%20Mobile%20computing%20%26%20teleworking%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%7D).