# graphviz MRecord spanning multiple lines - cannot reproduce?

Tags: visualization, graphviz

So, I've seen [Records spanning over multiple lines in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838717/records-spanning-over-multiple-lines-in-graphviz) and I tried to come up with a simpler test - which ended up being this:

```
graph G{
A11[ shape = Mrecord, label="A.11 Access Control|"+
"aa"];
}
```

So, I tried to test this online - ironically, the plotter recommended by https://graphviz.org themselves, which is http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/, fails on this example with `Expected ",", ";", "<", "\"", "]", NUMBER or UNICODE_STRING but "+" found.`:

[image: magjac graphviz]

... however, if I plot using Kroki https://kroki.io/#try - then it works?!

[image: kroki graphviz]

So, my questions are:

- Is this way of "splitting lines" in graphviz supported for some versions, and not for others? Or what other mistake could I have made?
- If versioning is the problem, how do I get to know which `graphviz` versions support this kind of "line splitting" - and how do I get to know, if this or that online plotter, supports this kind of line splitting (aside from pasting the example and letting it pass or fail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in "Graphviz Visual Editor" (provided by a Graphviz developer, but not part of the Graphviz package).
Using the command line **dot**, both versions of the concatenation syntax work.

From the language spec (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html):

```
As another aid for readability, dot allows double-quoted strings to span  
multiple physical lines using the standard C convention of a backslash  
immediately preceding a newline character². In addition, double-quoted  
strings can be concatenated using a '+' operator.
```

If you want/need to use the "Graphviz Visual Editor", this works:

```
graph G{
//  use backslash (\) at end-of-line
//    note, no internal double-quotes (")
B11[ shape = Mrecord, label="B.11 Access Control|\
BBB"];
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton, @sroush - that explains it! And good to know the "other" syntax (with escaping the newline, as opposed to the "+") for concatenating strings works